# conda cannot find installed module

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I've been trying to install "mkldnn" with conda, but came into this old issue of "conda installed but python cannot find installed module". The weird thing is after I added the path to python import, it still cannot find it.

Do you happen to have an idea why? Here are the methods I've tried and the results.

**Step 1:** I have tried building a new conda environment with Python3.6 and re-install `mkldnn` with conda. Still cannot find.

```
[yl5090@log-0 ~]$ module purge
[yl5090@log-0 ~]$ module load anaconda3/5.3.0
[yl5090@log-0 ~]$ conda create --name pytorch-mpi python=3.6
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/yl5090/.conda/envs/pytorch-mpi

  added / updated specs:
    - python=3.6


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    ca-certificates: 2018.03.07-0
    certifi:         2018.11.29-py36_0
    libedit:         3.1.20170329-h6b74fdf_2
    libffi:          3.2.1-hd88cf55_4
    libgcc-ng:       8.2.0-hdf63c60_1
    libstdcxx-ng:    8.2.0-hdf63c60_1
    ncurses:         6.1-he6710b0_1
    openssl:         1.1.1a-h7b6447c_0
    pip:             18.1-py36_0
    python:          3.6.7-h0371630_0
    readline:        7.0-h7b6447c_5
    setuptools:      40.6.2-py36_0
    sqlite:          3.25.3-h7b6447c_0
    tk:              8.6.8-hbc83047_0
    wheel:           0.32.3-py36_0
    xz:              5.2.4-h14c3975_4
    zlib:            1.2.11-h7b6447c_3

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
#
# To activate this environment, use:
# > source activate pytorch-mpi
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use:
# > source deactivate
#

[yl5090@log-0 ~]$ source activate pytorch-mpi
(pytorch-mpi) [yl5090@log-0 ~]$ conda install -c mingfeima mkldnn
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/yl5090/.conda/envs/pytorch-mpi

  added / updated specs:
    - mkldnn


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    intel-openmp: 2019.1-144
    mkl:          2019.1-144
    mkldnn:       0.16.1-0   mingfeima

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
(pytorch-mpi) [yl5090@log-0 ~]$ python
Python 3.6.7 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Oct 23 2018, 19:16:44)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mkldnn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mkldnn'
>>>
```

**Step 2:** I have checked there is no `mkldnn` package in the `sys.path` of this Python.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/yl5090/.conda/envs/pytorch-mpi/lib/python36.zip', '/home/yl5090/.conda/envs/pytorch-mpi/lib/python3.6', '/home/yl5090/.conda/envs/pytorch-mpi/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/yl5090/.conda/envs/pytorch-mpi/lib/python3.6/site-packages']


[yl5090@log-1 lab4]$ cd /home/yl5090/.conda/envs/pytorch-mpi/lib
[yl5090@log-1 lib]$ pwd
/home/yl5090/.conda/envs/pytorch-mpi/lib
[yl5090@log-1 lib]$ find . -type d -name "*mkldnn*" -print
[yl5090@log-1 lib]$
```

**Step 3:** I checked the import path of conda installed numpy and cannot find `mkldnn` in that path.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getfile(numpy)
'/home/yl5090/.conda/envs/pytorch-mpi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'

[yl5090@log-1 lib]$ cd /home/yl5090/.conda/envs/pytorch-mpi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
[yl5090@log-1 site-packages]$ ls
certifi                            pip
certifi-2018.11.29-py3.6.egg-info  pip-18.1-py3.6.egg-info
easy_install.py                    pkg_resources
mkl_fft                            __pycache__
mkl_fft-1.0.6-py3.6.egg-info       README.txt
mkl_random                         setuptools
mkl_random-1.0.2-py3.6.egg-info    setuptools-40.6.2-py3.6.egg-info
numpy                              wheel
numpy-1.15.4-py3.6.egg-info        wheel-0.32.3-py3.6.egg-info
```

**Step 4:** I did find an mkldnn installation in the `/.conda/pkgs` directory and added it to the python import path. But still cannot import it from python.

```
[yl5090@log-1 pkgs]$ ls /home/yl5090/.conda/pkgs | grep mkldnn
mkldnn-0.16.1-0
[yl5090@log-1 pkgs]$ cd mkldnn*
[yl5090@log-1 mkldnn-0.16.1-0]$ ls
include  info  lib  share

(load in python...)
>>> path = "/home/yl5090/.conda/pkgs"
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0, path)
>>> sys.path
['/home/yl5090/.conda/pkgs', '', '/home/yl5090/.conda/envs/pytorch-mpi/lib/python36.zip', '/home/yl5090/.conda/envs/pytorch-mpi/lib/python3.6', '/home/yl5090/.conda/envs/pytorch-mpi/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/yl5090/.conda/envs/pytorch-mpi/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
>>> import mkldnn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mkldnn'
```

The remaining reason I can think of now is Python cannot import `.so` files without an `__init__.py` file, but I'm not sure if that's the correct direction to go for this issue.

Finally, here are what's inside the `mkldnn` directory that I found, not sure if this is what conda has installed.

```
[yl5090@log-1 mkldnn-0.16.1-0]$ ls
include  info  lib  share
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you log what `which python`  and `conda list` output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. This is not a python package : https://github.com/intel/mkl-dnn It's a C/C++ module... Thanks!